# PHP - Select statement by username is returning 0 every time?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello so I am working on a project and I am attempting to select a user's userid based off of the username that is already provided. I am able to store the username easily using _POST since they input this information, however when I create a query to extract the userid, I get nothing! The code itself is running but its returning 0 every time, there has to be something wrong with my SQL, which is strange because Ive been working with SQL for the longest. I honestly don't see what's wrong with my code.

Here is my View. I just wrote this out for testing purposes

```
    <?php echo $_SESSION['userid'];?>
```

And here is my controller/model:

```
$username=$_POST['username'];
//protect the user this way
$username = stripslashes($username);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("tech_support2", $connection);
$query2 = mysql_query("select userid from users where username='$username'", $connection);
$_SESSION['userid'] = $query2;
```

Comment: Can you verify that you are getting the same results when running the query directly in MySQL for a given username?  If it works in MySQL directly, then we lay blame on the PHP code.

Comment: Can you do an `echo $username` from your script to see what the username is from the POST?

Comment: I can confirm SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE 'username' = 'test' returns one row

Comment: Hmm I think that may be the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use mysql_fetch_array to fetch the result from query2 object

```
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
 $_SESSION['userid']= $row["userid"];
```

Comment: I think this might be the problem, thanks Ill save this and work on it right now

Comment: As per the documentation "For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error."

Comment: It would be great next time you check the documentation first :-)